# Construct an equivalent formula in DNF

Tags: logic

A literal L is a formula of the shape p or :p, where p is a propositional variable. A co-clause K is a conjunction of literals, K ≡ L1 ∧ ... ∧ Lk. A formula F is in disjunctive normal form (DNF), if it is a disjunction of co-clauses, i.e. F ≡ K1 ∨ ... ∨ Km.

a) Describe how one can construct an equivalent formula in DNF from a given formula A ∈ F.

Can anyone help me with the question? Maybe a starting point for the question also would be helpful. I am bit confused because A is an element of F and F is already in DNF form.Thanks in advanced!

Comment: That's a weird question: what is $F$? And what is $A$? Are you sure it isn't asking you to show how *any* logical formula can be put into DNF?  (Which is a standard question ...)

Comment: F is a formula which is in DNF form and A is a element of F..Iam confused because if F is in DNF form, element of F should be in DNF form right ?

Comment: Here L is p or not p

Comment: Yes, any literal and co-clause is in DNF.

Comment: What is also weird is that it says $A \in F$ .. That suggests that $F$ is a set of formulas, rather than just a formula.

Comment: Yes, I am also confused...

Comment: @Bram28 here F can be any propositional formula

Comment: Ah!  That would have been my guess .... But we still have this mysterious  $A \in F$ ... what is that?

Comment: @Bram28 As my understanding A is also can be any propositional formula (but I am not sure). The question is about the general way of converting a formula to DNF.

Comment: Yeah, ok, I figured that was the question. Now, do you need to show how you can use algebra to step-by-step convert F into an equivalent DNF, or is it enough to demonstrate that for any F there exists an equivalent DNF?

Comment: According to my understanding, it would be sufficient to show for any F there exists an equivalent DNF. Thanks in advance!